# Implementing a one-to-many rnn model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to implement a "none-to-many" RNN of the following form: ["Learning to learn without gradient descent
by gradient descent"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLxev.png)

to reproduce this piece of work https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03824.pdf.

The input ("training-data") to this model is the function f and not a sequence of data as usual. What I would like to do is something like

```
x_0 = tf.constant(..)
h_0 = tf.constant(..)
f_params = tf.placeholder(..)

h = h_0
x = x_0

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units)

for _ in range(seq_length):
   y = f(x, f_params)
   x,h = cell([x,y],h)
```

But I can not find a way to get this to work. All examples that I can find online use tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn() or tf.nn.dynamic_rnn() to implement "many-to-many" or "many-to-one" architectures.